# Typescript 2.1 React cannot find module.

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a simple React/express app and I'm having an issue with the Typescript compiler and my components
container.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class Container extends React.Component{
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      state: ""
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>hello world</div>
    )
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import Container from "../components/container";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
let app = express();
app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
  ReactDOM.render(<Container/>,document.getElementById("app"));
});


app.listen(9999,()=>{

});
```

VS code highlights the callback inside app.get and says `Argument of type 'Container' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<any, any>'.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Container'.`

when I run the compiler I get errors about regular expressions on .
I'm using Typescript 2.1, last night's build.

Answer (score 1):

In your server.ts, the `ReactDOM.render(...)` method transpiles to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Container, null), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Notice how there is a `React.createElement(...)` method is substituted in place of `<Container />`. Because of this, you have to `import * as React from 'react'` inside of your server.ts file to satisfy the transpiled React variable, which should satisfy the type mismatch.